# Calculating $\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{x\sin{x}}{5-4\cos{x}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Calculate the following integral:$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{x\sin{x}}{5-4\cos{x}}\,\mathrm dx$$

I can calculate the integral on $[0,\pi]$,but I want to know how to do it on $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$.

Comment: Some properties of definite integral must be used as the indefinite one is not elementary http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Csin%7Bx%7D%7D%7B5-4%5Ccos%7Bx%7D%7Ddx

Comment: Mathematica gives a closed form for what it's worth: $$\frac{1}{16} \left(-\Im\left(4 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)-4
   \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)+\pi  \log
   \left(\frac{6561}{400}\right)-8 \log (2) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-\log
   (16) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\log (16) \tan ^{-1}(2)\right)$$

Comment: I do not understand your question: if you can compute the integral on $[0,\pi]$, why can't you do the same on the smaller interval $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$?

Comment: First, we have$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x\sin{x}}{5-4\cos{x}}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\log{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi}\log{(\frac{5}{4}-\cos{x})}dx$$Now let $I(q)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\log{(q-\cos{x})}dx$, we have$$I'(q)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{(q-\cos{x})}dx$$Next,let $t=\tan{\frac{x}{2}}$ and we can work it out:$$I'(q)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{q^2-1}}$$Then we integrate it back:$$I(q)=\pi\log{\frac{q+\sqrt{q^2-1}}{2}}$$.Thus,we have$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x\sin{x}}{5-4\cos{x}}d=\frac{\pi}{2}\log{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{I(\frac{5}{4})}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}\log{\frac{3}{2}}$$.@Avitus

Comment: But, when the integral limit becomes $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$,we'll have $$I'(q)=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{1}{(q-\cos{x})}dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{q^2-1}}(\pi/2-\tan^{-1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{q^2-1}}})$$,which I failed to integrate back.@Avitus

Comment: @YMJou, you should write down that comment as an answer.

Comment: Use the [Weierstrauss substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) to arrive at $$ \int_1^\infty \frac{\arctan(2t) \cdot 4t}{\left(1 + t^2\right)\left(9t^2 + 1\right)} \ dt $$ I'm not sure how useful this is though. One interesting thing is that both factors of the denominators integrate to an arctangent function by themselves, although I'm not sure if that is at all relevant.

Comment: @DonAntonio But I failed on the interval $[\pi/2,\pi]$

Answer (score 65):

$$\begin{align}\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\frac{x\sin x}{5-4\cos x}dx&=\pi\left(\frac{\ln3}2-\frac{\ln2}4-\frac{\ln5}8\right)-\frac12\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac12\right)\\&=\pi\left(\frac{\ln3}2-\frac{\ln2}4-\frac{\ln5}8\right)-\frac12\Im\,\chi_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{-1}}2\right),\end{align}$$
where  $\operatorname{Ti}_2(z)$ is the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html) and $\Im\,\chi_\nu(z)$ is the [imaginary part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ImaginaryPart.html) of the [Legendre chi function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresChi-Function.html).

---

*Hint:*
Use the following Fourier series and integrate termwise:
$$\frac{\sin x}{5-4\cos x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n x}{2^{n+1}}.$$

Answer (score 12):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}{x\sin\pars{x} \over 5 - 4\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}{x\sin\pars{x} \over 5 - 4\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
> ={1 \over 4}\int_{x\ =\ \pi/2}^{x\ =\ \pi}x\,\dd\bracks{\ln\pars{5 - 4\cos\pars{x}}}
> \\[3mm]&={\pi\ln\pars{5 - 4\cos\pars{\pi}}
>   -\pars{\pi/2}\ln\pars{5 - 4\cos\pars{\pi/2}} \over 4}
> -{1 \over 4}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\ln\pars{5 - 4\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 8}\,\pi\ln\pars{81 \over 5}
> -{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{5 + 4\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 8}\,\pi\ln\pars{81 \over 25}
> -{1 \over 4}\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{1 + \alpha\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
> \ \mbox{where}\ \boxed{\ \alpha \equiv {4 \over 5} < 1\ }\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{1}
> \end{align}

With $\ds{x \equiv 2\arctan\pars{t}\quad\imp\quad t = \tan\pars{x \over 2}}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{1 + \alpha\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
=\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + \alpha\,{2t \over 1 + t^{2}}}\,
{2\,\dd t \over 1 + t^{2}}
\\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln\pars{t^{2} + 2\alpha t + 1} \over 1 + t^{2}}\,\dd t
-2\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + t^{2}} \over 1 + t^{2}}\,\dd t}
^{\ds{-{\rm G} + \half\,\pi\ln\pars{2} }}
\\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln\pars{\bracks{z - t}\pars{z^{*} - t}} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\dd t
+ 2{\rm G} - \pi\ln\pars{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\ds{z \equiv -\alpha - \root{1 - \alpha^{2}}\ \ic=-\,{4 \over 5} - {3 \over 5}\,\ic}$ and $\ds{\rm G}$ is the [Catalan Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant). Note that
$\ds{z^{*} = {1 \over z}}$.

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{1 + \alpha\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
> \\[2mm]&=2{\rm G} - \pi\ln\pars{2}
> +2\Im\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - t/z} \over t - \ic}\,\dd t
> + \int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - zt} \over t - \ic}\,\dd t}
> \\[2mm]&=2{\rm G} - \pi\ln\pars{2}
> +2\Im\bracks{\int_{0}^{1/z}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t - \ic z^{*}}\,\dd t
> + \int_{0}^{z}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t - \ic z}\,\dd t}
> \\[2mm]&=2{\rm G} - \pi\ln\pars{2}
> -2\Im\bracks{\int_{0}^{z^{*}}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{t} \over t - \ic z^{*}}\,\dd t
> + \int_{0}^{z}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{t} \over t - \ic z}\,\dd t}\tag{3}
> \end{align}
>   where ${{\rm Li_{s}}\pars{z}}$ is the [PolyLogaritm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Also,
$$
\int_{0}^{\xi}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{t} \over t - \ic \xi}\,\dd t
=-\ln\pars{1 - \xi}\ln\pars{\bracks{1 + \ic}\xi \over \xi + \ic}
+{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\ic \over \xi + \ic}
+{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\ic\,{\xi - 1 \over \xi + \ic}}\tag{4}
$$

> $\ds{\color{#88f}{\mbox{The final result was found by combining}\ \pars{1}, \pars{2}, \pars{3}\ \mbox{and}\ \pars{4}}}$.